# Laravel Imap cant check if mail has attachment if setFetchBody is false | setFetchAttachment does not have any effect

Tags: php, laravel, email, imap

I use [laravel imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap).

I am fetchting the mails of a mailbox, which works great.

I need to display an information whether mails have an attachment.

For this I was using this code, which WORKED:

```
$aMessage = $selectedFolder->messages()->setFetchFlags(true)
->setFetchAttachment(true)->setFetchBody(true)->leaveUnread()->limit(40, $highest_page)->get();
```

The Problem is the load times were bad. To fix this I set setFetchBody to false, which greatly improved the load time. I dont need the body in the overview anyway:

```
$aMessage = $selectedFolder->messages()->setFetchFlags(true)
->setFetchAttachment(true)->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()->limit(40, $highest_page)->get();
```

Now even with setFetchAttachment(true) the attachment information is lost.
`$oMessage->hasAttachments()` always returns `false`.

If I switch back `setFetchBody` to `true` it works.

`setFetchAttachment` does not seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If the attachment information is part of the body, how would I improve performance? The webclient somehow does it AND knows about attachments.

Comment: Attachments _are_ part of the mail body, so without fetching that in the first place, what you want is likely not possible.

Comment: @04FS Damn... But how does the webclient achieve such a good performance when loading mails AND it knows about the attachment. I have the same performance without the body. But with the body I get a timeout.